# Special Relativity in water

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, refraction, observers

If there are 2 observers in water moving relative to each other as well as to water, they measure different speeds of light.  So does time dilation occur for them? (since Time dilation is based on constancy of speed of light)

Comment: Yes, but any attempt to move at significant enough speed to measure special relativity will put you squarely in what-if.xkcd land.

Answer (score 1):

Relativity just requires "constant speed of light in vacuum". It makes no claims about the speed of light in a medium.

When you are moving relative to water, you will observe a different speed of light depending on your relative velocity. But you will still have all the other effects of relativity at work - such as time dilation.

Comment: In that case it should be possible to observe photons move backwards if the medium is moving relative to you faster than light in that medium. Has that ever been observed? I'm thinking Cherenkov radiation as the virtual photons you produce can't catch up to you and become real instead.

Comment: Since you only observe photons when you interact with them, I'm not sure how you can observe one moving away from you, but it's possible for some objects to move faster than light in water and Cherenkov radiation is a byproduct of that.  Brief explanation here.    http://www.physlink.com/Education/AskExperts/ae219.cfm

Answer (score 0):

The opening statement "If there are 2 observers in water moving relative to each other as well as to water, they measure different speeds of light" is false. Both observers will measure the same speed for light, and therefore, relativistic effects will occur.

Unlike sound, light does not require a medium through which to travel, so the speed of the medium (in this case water) is irrelevant.

Search the web for "submarine paradox" for proof.